# How do you set up a Solidity dev environment?

Tags: ethereum

I'm familiar with coding as far as setting up homebrew for classic consoles. I can read it. Pray writing it.
So what I want to do is compile some code from dapp university. I installed Gitsavvy, solc, cmake, visual studio 2019 because m$ is hiding 2017, and the other necessary installs. I followed a guide from medium.com
Sublime text is now aware of the Ethereum syntax Solidity and Vyper but it does not ever have a build system. How do you fix "No Build System" in Sublime Text for a solidity environment?
Thank You

Comment: Learn Ubuntu Linux. Delete Windows from your hard drive.

Comment: I use vscode as editor, and hardhat for compiling, deploying a private test network, and deploying to actual networks. If you're a new id suggest you give this challenge a try: https://github.com/scaffold-eth/scaffold-eth/tree/challenge-1-decentralized-staking

As for the dev environment, anything ca do, you just user what you're most comfortable with.

You should learn how to use hardhat (and / or) truffle & ganache since those are the main tools used currently in the professional field to compile contracts.

Comment: Thank you for kindly chaining that. I have a good direction to go too.
I would learn Ubuntu but I'm not ready for that kind of commitment.